# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de una fila y mostrarlos en un modal?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
<table class="uk-table" id="mitabla">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Oficina</th>
                                <th>Numero de Oficina</th>
                                <th>Turno</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>tipo de tramite</th>
                                <th>Acción</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body_tramites">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

De la cual tomo los valores con el siguiente **AJAX**:

```
if (response.success) {
                $.each(response.data.tramites, function( key, value ) { 
                     $.each( value, function (trkey,trvalue) {
                            switch(trkey){  
                                case 'tr_id':

                                content+=`
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none" >
                                        ${trvalue}
                                    </td>
                                 `;
                                 id = trvalue;
                                 document.getElementById('titulo_comprobacion').innerHTML = id;
                                break;

                                case 'tr_oficina':
                                content+=`
                                <td>
                                    ${trvalue}
                                </td>
                            `;
                                    break;      
                                case 'num_oficina':
                                    content+=`
                                        <td>
                                            ${trvalue}
                                        </td>
                                    `;
                                    break;

                                case 'tr_turno':
                                content+=`
                                        <td>
                                            ${trvalue}
                                        </td>
                                    `;
                                    break;
                                    case 'tr_cronometro':
                                    var limite = '00:00:30'
                                    var cronometro = trvalue;
                                    if (cronometro > limite) {
                                        content+=`
                                        <td style="background-color: rgb(218, 78, 71);" >
                                            ${cronometro}
                                        </td>
                                    `;
                                    } else {
                                        content+=`
                                        <td style="background-color: rgb(28, 204, 28);" >
                                            ${cronometro}
                                        </td>
                                    `;  
                                    }

                                    break;

                                case 'tr_tipo_tramite':
                                content+=`
                                        <td>
                                            ${trvalue}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        <i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file " href="#modal-full" uk-toggle >search</i>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    `;
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                 });       
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#body_tramites').empty();
            $('#body_tramites').append(content);
        },
```

Comment: mira este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145949/concatenar-valores-en-input-con-jquery#comment273644_145949