# concatenar valores en input con jquery

Tags: html, jquery, html5

tengo una tabla html la cual cuando se da clic en una fila me obtiene un valor que yo quiero recuperar,
como puedo concatenar valores en un input cada vez que obtenga un valor

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var total = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();
  alert(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>2.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿quieres concatenar el texto o sumar los valores?

Comment: @ChristopherVilla quiero concatenar valores

Comment: no te sale mejor mandarlo a un array con push?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez es que no los he usado

Comment: creo que ya te respondieron abajo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente solo falta agregar el código para leer y concatenar al input :

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var textoInput = $("#final").val(); //obtenemos el valor actual
  var total = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();
  var nuevoTexto = textoInput + total; //concatenamos
  $("#final").val(nuevoTexto); //aplicamos el nuevo valor al input
  //alert(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>2.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="final" value="">
```

De esta manera se concatenará el texto, ¿es lo que buscabas?

Comment: @Cristopher asi es gracias

Comment: sirvio de mucho.
Como haria para que todos los datos enviarlo a una base de datos en forma de cadenas.
Utilizando ASP.NET.NET CORE MVC Y SQL SERVER 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Obtienes el contenido del input luego lo concatenas con el texto obtenido y lo vuelves a asignar al input

```js
$("table tbody tr").click(function() {
  var total = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();
  var $Input = $('#ConcatInput');
  $Input.val($Input.val()+total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>celda 1</td>
      <td>celda 2</td>
      <td>celda 3</td>
      <td>2.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="ConcatInput" />
```